# How to set uuid-ossp as a default extension for whole server?

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I installed **uuid-ossp** for the default PostgreSQL database (postgres) using the following sql commands but whenever I create a new database I am forced to run the same commands once again for every new database.

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
ALTER EXTENSION "uuid-ossp" SET SCHEMA public;
```

Is there any way to install **uuid-ossp** once and ensure that every new database will have **uuid-ossp** enabled by default?

**PS**. I use PostgreSQL ver. 13.1

Comment: If you only need it to have `uuid_generate_v4()` then there is no reason in Postgres 13 any more as it now has a built in `gen_random_uuid()` See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`CREATE DATABASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html) command always clones some existing template database.

If this parameter is not specified, postgresql uses the `template1` database as the default. Thus, any prior changes in `template1` database will be part of the new database (unless another `TEMPLATE`  has been specified explicitly).

You need connect to `template1` database and create the uuid-ossp extension in this database.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I modified `template1` Everything works smoothly as I want.